# Fantasy Movie - Man who wants revenge

Tags: identify-this-movie, fantasy

I can't remember the year it came out but it is in color and definitely not something from the 90s and the language is English.

It starts out with a field, I think it was burned down, and a man is walking when he meets two guards and they ask for money for letting him go.

He was an outsider (from outside the Kingdom). He gave them a coin, and then killed them and took their money.

He enters some land where other tribes live, or perhaps outsiders.

He sees a pot with food and starts eating. He then gets knocked out by 2-3 guys. When he wakes up, his hands are tied. It is nighttime and he can hear a woman's and a man's voice. They are about to rape a woman in front of her father when he gets out of the rope and kills them.

I believe now some guards come and ask them and starts to make trouble (one of them is the son of the King). The man then kills the guards and ask the King's son to choose between death or cutting his own eye out. The King's son then cuts out his own eye but then the man gives him a message to deliver to his father the King.

The movie ends with you understanding that the man is, in fact, the Kings brother and he betrayed him and sold his son to be a slave.

Comment: If you can say more, you really should - any detail you remember may help someone else identify this movie for you. Among other things - is this fantasy or historical?

Comment: I Can remember the entire movie. And its fantasy.

Comment: Like i Said it is collored and language is english. I cant remember The exact time i watched it. But its defiently from 2000 and up. Also i think The movies name was Sword of ..... cant remember The last part

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you're looking for [Sword of Vengeance (2015)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3622332/)

The movie is centered around a Prince looking for vengeance on his uncle:

> the film proceeds to depict the efforts of Norman prince Shadow Walker (Stanley Weber) to exact vengeance on his uncle, the ruthless Earl Durant (Karl Roden), who rules the north of England in Saddam Hussein-style with his equally sociopathic sons Lord Artus (Gianna Giardinelli) and Lord Roman (Edward Akrout). We eventually learn that Shadow Walker, who rallies a large band of exiled rebel farmers improbably led by the beautiful Anna (Annabelle Wallis) to his cause, has a personal stake in the matter since it was his uncle who murdered his father.

[Source](http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/review/sword-vengeance-film-review-782816)

[Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BgDjE4PP5-I)